# TFS Email Configuration

Tags: email, configuration

We have moved our TFS data tier server to another machine.  Everything was reconfigured and is working EXCEPT email alerts.  Test emails are sent just fine.  However, alerts are not happening.  When I checked the event viewer, I'm seeing the following error:

ds:OLDSERVERINSTANCE db:Tfs_Configuration errors:-1 exception:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

So, it appears that the email is still looking at the old database (which has been retired).  Where/how can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this scenario.  The TFSJobAgent wasn't smart enough on reboot to recognize the data tier change.  Doing the following worked:
1.  Stop iis
2.  Stop the TFSJobAgent
3.  Start the TFSJobAgent
4.  Start iis